# Magento 2.2.x: Persistent Checkout can't be disabled

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, session, persistent

The problem is even when i disable the "persistent checkout", it still work as normal.
Its a magento default module, so i think this is a magento 2 bug.
[image]

After a day working on this, i still don't know how this work. I mean i guess they use cookie or session to store the cart after customer log out.

Then after guest login, they will use that session or cookie to update the cart.
But i don't know how they do that.

The module is "module-persistent" (default magento module).
Thanks.

Comment: have you clean the configuration cache?

Comment: Yes i did serveral time, as i said, i was working on this all day long, so the first thing i have thinking of is "clear cache" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so after a day looking for solution, i've found something.
But this is only a temporary solution.
So here is the idea:
We override the magento/customer/account/logout by plugin, then we will truncate the cart.

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout">
        <plugin name="remove_cart_before_logout" type="Fudu\Customer\Plugin\Controller\Account\Logout" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

> Plugin/Controller/Account/Logout

```
<?php 
namespace Fudu\Customer\Plugin\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout as CustomerLogout;

class Logout
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Persistent\Helper\Data $persistentData
    ){
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->persistentData = $persistentData;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(CustomerLogout $subject)
    {
        if(!$this->persistentData->isEnabled()){
            $this->cart->truncate()->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, we have to override this file too, in case customer doesn't logout, they close the tab and open a private browser:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\Session" type="Gssi\Checkout\Model\Session" />
</config>
```

> Magento\Checkout\Model\Session.php

```
public function loadCustomerQuote()
    {
        if (!$this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        // put this in, and everything is still the same.
        if(!$this->persistentData->isEnabled()){
            return $this;
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('load_customer_quote_before', ['checkout_session' => $this]);

        try {
            $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId());
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $customerQuote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
        }
        $customerQuote->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) {
            if ($this->getQuoteId()) {
                $this->quoteRepository->save(
                    $customerQuote->merge($this->getQuote())->collectTotals()
                );
            }

            $this->setQuoteId($customerQuote->getId());

            if ($this->_quote) {
                $this->quoteRepository->delete($this->_quote);
            }
            $this->_quote = $customerQuote;
        } else {
            $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            $this->getQuote()->setCustomer($this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject())
                ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
                ->collectTotals();
            $this->quoteRepository->save($this->getQuote());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```